# Http referer and bookmark

Tags: bookmarks, http-referer

I'm visiting a website and soon I click on a bookmark in my browser. A new website is opened. My question is: 
Does the referer data (which is submitted to the new website) only contain the bookmark info or is my last visited website also within the data?

I'm really not sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

Testing with Google Chrome and [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) shows that Chrome doesn't send a `Referer` header when fetching a page after clicking a bookmark.

Answer (score 2):

An HTTP referrer is only sent if the user arrives from a resource with a URL (generally, another web page).  Typing in a URL, clicking on a link in a desktop email program, word document, etc., or opening a bookmark all do not send a referrer, because those sources do not have URLs of their own.

> The Referer[sic] request-header field allows the client to specify,
>   for the server's benefit, the address (URI) of the resource from which
>   the Request-URI was obtained (the "referrer", although the header
>   field is misspelled.) The Referer request-header allows a server to
>   generate lists of back-links to resources for interest, logging,
>   optimized caching, etc. It also allows obsolete or mistyped links to
>   be traced for maintenance. The Referer field MUST NOT be sent if the
>   Request-URI was obtained from a source that does not have its own URI,
>   such as input from the user keyboard.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Note that there is no guarantee that a referrer will ever be sent, even if the source *does* have a URL.